# With CanCan, how do i limit ability based on association / child attribute

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, postgresql, cancan, rails-activerecord

I have a db setup where there are many users, which have roles of member or admin. Each user has many cars. Each car has many timeslips

So, how do i limit a user's ability to edit a Timeslip only if he is the owner of the parent car.

In CanCan:

```
class Ability
    include CanCan::Ability

    def initialize(user)
        user ||= User.new # guest user (not logged in)
        if user.has_role? :admin
            can :manage, :all
        elsif user.has_role? :member
            can :manage, Car, :user_id => user.id
            can :manage, Timeslip, :car => {:user_id => user.id}
        end
    end
end
```

so the line `can :manage, Timeslip, :car => {:user_id => user.id}` is where i need some help.

Because Timeslip is an association/child of Car, i need to check that its parent car.user_id = the Cancan user.id

I thought how i wrote this is in line with the CanCan docs, but where have I gone wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There might be a shorter way to write it, but this will work:

```
can :manage, Timeslip do |timeslip|
     timeslip.car.user_id == user.id
end
```

Comment: i get `undefined method "user_id" for nil:NilClass`

Comment: It means you have a timeslip that has no car associated to it.

Comment: I changed this to `can [:edit,:update,:destroy], Timeslip do |timeslip|
        timeslip.user == user
      end` and its working now. I'm using my **has_one :user, :through => :car** for some reason, it wasn't finding the car association? but i can see it with debug... dunno

Answer (score 0):

This is what's working for me: `can :manage, Timeslip, car: { roles: { id: user.role_ids } }`